# Why isn't this xcopy command not working?

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to run a simple xcopy batch script but I am facing some difficoulties.
Here is the script

```
SET SRC=C:\FOLDER1\FOLDER2
SET DEST=V:\FOLDER1

FOR /D %%d in (%SRC%\*) do xcopy /S /I /y /exclude:%SRC%\exclude.txt %%d  V:\FOLDER1\%%~nxd
```

Basically this script should copy some of the subfolders of `C:\FOLDER1\FOLDER2` (excluded.txt contains a list of directories to exclude) and its content to the destination. However when I run the scripts, altough no errors are thrown, **NO FILES OR FOLDERS get copied.** What am I doing wrong?

Interestingly if I run the following script INSIDE `FOLDER2`, everything procedes as expected.

```
FOR /D %%A in (*) DO xcopy /S /I /y /exclude:exclude.txt %%A  V:\FOLDER1\%%A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xcopy "C:\FOLDER1\FOLDER2" "V:\FOLDER1" /e /i /y
```

You mention nothing about excluding any folders.

Comment: Show your excluded.txt. Any match or partial match will exclude the file/folder.

Comment: dashboard\
forbidden\
img\
restricted\
xampp\

Comment: Each folder is written on a new line

Comment: It says "0 files copied" for each subfolder